# Манипуляции с датой

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Мне нужно вывести дату из бд.  + если дата не менялась 10 дней -кр. цвет 5 дней -оран. сегодня - зелен.

контроллер

```
$timestamp = strtotime($seldate);
$timestamp -= 86400 * 10;
$date10    = date("d.m.y", $timestamp);
$timestamp = strtotime($seldate);
$timestamp -= 86400 * 5;
$date5     = date("d.m.y", $timestamp);
$timestamp = strtotime($seldate);
$timestamp -= 86400;
$date1        = date("d.m.y", $timestamp);
$data['time'] = "08:30";
```

вьюшка

```
$date         = date("d.m.y", strtotime($item->disla_date));
$tim          = $item->time;
if ((strtotime($date) <= $date5) and (strtotime($date) > $date10)) {
    echo "<td style='color: #FF8C00;'>" . $date . "</td>";
} elseif (strtotime($date) <= $date10) {
    echo "<td style='color: #FF0000;'>" . $date . "</td>";
} elseif (strtotime($seldate) == (strtotime($date)) or ($date1 == (strtotime($date)) and ($tim > $time))) {
    echo "<td style='color: #00FF00;'>" . $date . "</td>";
} else {
    echo "<td>" . $date . "</td>";
}
```

Это не работает. Не выводит нужную палитру цветов. Как можно это исправить?

Заранее спасибо!

ПРАВКА1
Исправила код на след.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($seldate);         
        $date10 = date("d.m.y", $timestamp - 86400 * 10);
        $date5 = date("d.m.y", $timestamp - 86400 * 5);
        $date1 = date("d.m.y", $timestamp - 86400);
```

и вывод

```
$date = date("d.m.y", strtotime($item->date));

                    if($date <= $date5 and $date > $date10)
                    {
                        echo "<td style='color:orange;'>".$date."</td>"; 
                    }
                    elseif($date <= $date10)
                    {
                        echo "<td style='color: red;'>".$date."</td>"; 
                    }
                    elseif($date1 == $date OR $timestamp == $date and $item->time > $time)
                    {
                        echo "<td style='color: green;'>".$date."</td>"; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<td>".$date."</td>";
                    }
```

но возникла проблема, когда я выбираю прошлый месяц, все работает правильно все условия выполняются, но когда я выбираю этот месяц - то все подчеркивается красным?
почему так?

Comment: как дата в БД хранится?

Comment: в базе тип date

Comment: аццтой.

почему  не хранить в БД дату в INT? всего 4байта вместо 8 DATE? да и работать с типом INT намного удобнее. Я про unixtime + 3 часа -100 часов, +30дней, 3 месяца и прочее.
Если что я тут помогать не буду, неудобные данные в неудобоваримом формате - буэ. сорри.

сколько лишних проверок и переводов в числа 

    strtotime($date)
    $timestamp = strtotime($seldate);
    $timestamp -= 86400 * 10;
    $date10    = date("d.m.y", $timestamp);
    $timestamp = strtotime($seldate);

Comment: @Shrek, хоть бы изучили вопрос, прежде чем такую чушь нести.

Тип DATE занимает [3 байта в MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html#id681824) и [4 байта в Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html)

> Я про unixtime + 3 часа -100 часов, +30дней, 3 месяца и прочее.

Конечно, `SELECT date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH` и `SELECT date + INTERVAL 30 DAYS` - это сложнее и запутаннее, чем высчитывать секунды для каждого месяца с проверкой високосный ли год и нету ли в данном месяце перехода на летнее время. Про часовые зоны я уж вообще молчу.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov Летнее время нигде не используется сейчас. Нет ну есть ряд стран и мелких пунктов, но уверен на 100% что в интернет-магазине, расположенному в России они заказ не сделают, им на это побоку.

Часовые зоны - афигеть, и что многие пользуются переводом часовых зон? (да запомни IP пользователя и все, узнай 1 раз его пояс занеси в БД и закешируй)если информация нужна для менеджера когда упал заказ по его времени, ему не важно время у клиента. он посмотрит на время в админке, где будет написано что там +4 или -8.

Comment: Да проверка високосного года это вааще атас! И что раз в год проверил параметр, записал в переменную и пользуйся закешированными данными, в чем проблема? зачем 365 дней в году по 24 часа в сутки 7 дней в неделю пересчитывать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strtotime('-10 days') < $timestamp) {
    // $timestamp старше 10 дней
}

if (strtotime('-5 days') < $timestamp) {
    // $timestamp старше 5 дней
}

if (date('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-d', $timestamp)) {
    // дата $timestamp равна сегодняшней
}
```